# Null pointer exception using Binary Trees

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

I have a project which is "Start with the tree.java program (Listing 8.1) and modify it to create a binary
tree from a string of letters (like A, B, and so on) entered by the user. Each
letter will be displayed in its own node. Construct the tree so that all the nodes
that contain letters are leaves. Parent nodes can contain some non-letter
symbol like +. Make sure that every parent node has exactly two children.
Don’t worry if the tree is unbalanced. Note that this will not be a search tree;
there’s no quick way to find a given node."

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Node
{
    public String iData; // data item (key)
    public Node leftChild; // this node’s left child
    public Node rightChild; // this node’s right child
    public void displayNode() // display ourself
    {
        System.out.print('{');
        System.out.print(iData);
        System.out.print("} ");
    }
} // end class Node

class Tree
{
    private Node root; // first node of tree
    public void setNode(Node newNode)
    {root = newNode;}
    public Node getNode()
    {return root;}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
    public Tree() // constructor
    { root = null; } // no nodes in tree yet
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public void traverse(int traverseType)
{
    switch(traverseType)
    {
        case 1: System.out.print("\nPreorder traversal: ");
        preOrder(root);
        break;
        case 2: System.out.print("\nInorder traversal: ");
        inOrder(root);
        break;
        case 3: System.out.print("\nPostorder traversal: ");
        postOrder(root);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
private void preOrder(Node localRoot)
{
    if(localRoot != null)
    {
        System.out.print(localRoot.iData + " ");
        preOrder(localRoot.leftChild);
        preOrder(localRoot.rightChild);
    }
}
//A function I made to try and get the letters into leaves.
void preOrderLeaves(Node localRoot, Tree[] forest, int i)
{
    if(localRoot != null)
    {
        localRoot.iData = "+";
        localRoot.leftChild.iData = "+";
        localRoot.rightChild = forest[i].getNode();
        preOrderLeaves(localRoot.leftChild, forest, i + 1);
        preOrderLeaves(localRoot.rightChild, forest, i + 1);
    }
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
private void inOrder(Node localRoot)
{
    if(localRoot != null)
    {
        inOrder(localRoot.leftChild);
        System.out.print(localRoot.iData + " ");
        inOrder(localRoot.rightChild);
    }
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
private void postOrder(Node localRoot)
{
    if(localRoot != null)
    {
        postOrder(localRoot.leftChild);
        postOrder(localRoot.rightChild);
        System.out.print(localRoot.iData + " ");
    }
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public void displayTree()
{
    Stack globalStack = new Stack();
    globalStack.push(root);
    int nBlanks = 32;
    boolean isRowEmpty = false;
    System.out.println(
    "......................................................");
    while(isRowEmpty==false)
    {
        Stack localStack = new Stack();
        isRowEmpty = true;
        for(int j=0; j<nBlanks; j++)
        System.out.print(' ');
        while(globalStack.isEmpty()==false)
        {
            Node temp = (Node)globalStack.pop();
            if(temp != null)
        {
                System.out.print(temp.iData);
                localStack.push(temp.leftChild);
                localStack.push(temp.rightChild);
                if(temp.leftChild != null ||
                        temp.rightChild != null)
                    isRowEmpty = false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("--");
            localStack.push(null);
            localStack.push(null);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<nBlanks*2-2; j++)
            System.out.print(' ');
        } // end while globalStack not empty
        System.out.println();
        nBlanks /= 2;
        while(localStack.isEmpty()==false)
            globalStack.push( localStack.pop() );
        } // end while isRowEmpty is false
        System.out.println(
        "......................................................");
    } // end displayTree()
        // -------------------------------------------------------------
}


public class Leaves 
{
   //I Tried to create an array of individual trees and then add them to a 
   //larger tree
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Tree[] forest = new Tree[10];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        String letter;
        System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");
        letter = sc.nextLine();

        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.iData = letter;
        forest[i].setNode(newNode); //This line causes the null pointer exception

    }

    Tree letterTree = new Tree();

    letterTree.preOrderLeaves(letterTree.getNode(), forest, 0);

    letterTree.displayTree();
}

}
```

I get a Null point exception when I try to set forest to the new node. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Tree[] forest = new Tree[10];
```

This line creates an array of 10 elements for Trees but doesn't initialize any of them. You might want to through iterate through the array and instantiate every element, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < forest.length; ++i)
  fores[i] = new Tree();
```

I also sincerly hope all that code isn't in the same file. Try to have each class in a different file.